# How to prove that a functional is locally Lipscitz?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $X$ be a real Banach space and $\Omega$ a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$. We have the following functional, for  $u \in X$ and $p \in (0, \infty)$:
$$F(u(x)) = \int_{\Omega}^{} \dfrac{|u(x)|^{p-1} u(x)}{|x|^p} dx, ~\forall x \in \Omega.$$
I want to prove that this functional is locally Lipschitz,
satisfying the Lipschitz condition such
$$|F(u)-F(v)| \leq K |u-v|~\forall u,v \in N,$$
where there is a neighbourhood $N$ of $u$ and a constant $K$ depending on $N$.\
Applying the latter, we have
\begin{align*}
|F(u)-F(v)| &\leq \left \vert \int_{\Omega}^{} \dfrac{|u(x)|^{p-1} u(x)}{|x|^p} dx - \int_{\Omega}^{} \dfrac{|v(x)|^{p-1} v(x)}{|x|^p} dx \right \vert \\
            &\leq \left \vert \int_{\Omega}^{} \dfrac{|u(x)|^{p-1} u(x) - |v(x)|^{p-1} v(x)}{|x|^p} dx \right \vert \\
            &\leq \int_{\Omega}^{} \dfrac{\left \vert |u(x)|^{p-1} u(x) - |v(x)|^{p-1} v(x) \right \vert}{|x|^p} dx.
\end{align*}
I got stuck in here and don't know how to proceed after this?

Comment: What is $u(x)$? And what is $|u-v|$?I cannot make sense out of this question.

Comment: You need to specify $X$

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy $u(x)$ is a function of  $X$, and $|u−v|=|u(x)-v(x)|$.

Comment: You started with 'For $u \in X'$ causing  confusion. You are trying to prove an inequality where LHS is  a number and RHS is  a funvtion. You need a norm on the space of functions on $X$ for this to make sense. A lot of cleaning up is needed,.

Comment: @Meowdog Let's say $X= W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N)$ is the fractional Sobolev space
$W^{s,p}(\mathbb{R}^N) = \left\lbrace  u \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^N)~:~\dfrac{\vert u(x)-u(u)\vert}{\vert x-y \vert^{\frac{N}{p}+s}} \in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{2N})\right\rbrace$